# JQuery ajax get error :unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to do an ajax get to retrieve data from  OData service, this is my code :

```
$.ajax({
  url : "https://systempath/servicename",
  type: "GET", //or POST?
  dataType: "jsonp",

  xhrFields: 
   {
  withCredentials: true
   },
  beforeSend: function (request)
   {
  request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic");
   },

  success: function(){alert("ok")},
  error: function(){alert("error")}
})
```

But i get this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

If i consult the network, i find my response in JSON format, but the error function is executed not the success function.

This is my response:
[image: responseOdata]

Comment: can you post the json response

Comment: @Pabs123 i have updated my question

Comment: Post JSON response as **text**, not image.

Comment: it's almost definitely poorly formatted json, we need to see the full response. run it through http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Probably your service return wrong formatted json

Comment: @GeneR my json is valid

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is the **dataType** that you defined, make sure that the responses headers are corrects with your req. Test with the `dataType:'text',` this might works fine.

Comment: i'm getting : Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401                                                    So I'm using jsonp to avoid cross origin error

Comment: for the jsonp works you might pass a callback attribute in url with a callbackName ?callback=callbackname

Comment: and the answer in the server must be callbackname(){/*javascript code*/}